# How to create a decision table using Seleium/Xebium scenario in Fitnesse

Tags: selenium, fitnesse

I have create a couple of Scenarios in fitnesse using Xebium/Selenium. They works nice but I'd like to create a decision table from one of my scenario.

So I try with the following:

```
| Verifiera ärendet | selenium driver fixture |
| tabellRadsNr | längd | bredd | grisar | höns | getter | får | kod | felbeskrivning |
| 19 | 50 | 20 | 201 | 0 | 0 | 0 | R110 | Nekad |
```

And ends up with:

```
Could not invoke constructor for VerifieraÄrendet[1]
The instance decisionTable_25. does not exist
```

The scenario "Verifiera ärendet" works when I run it by itself so I guess that I am missing something....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I mixed up parameter names and their value names. So the structure basically is

```
| scenarioname parametername2 |
| parametervaluename1  | parametervaluename2 |
| row1value1 | row1value2 |
| row2value1 | row2value2 |
```